# Web project images missing when running in VS2013, works perfect in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have a C# MVC web site which was built in Visual Studio 2012. It works as intended, and when I run locally for testing and such it works and looks great.  However I have now installed Visual Studio 2013 and although the project compiles and runs correctly, the images are all missing when running locally.  I am assuming this has something to do with the fact that 2012 runs VS web development server and 2013 is running IISexpress??  It just looks like the image folder is missing - everything else works great!
Ideas?!

Comment: Build Action = Content?

Comment: I'm guessing you've tried manually re-adding the images to the project?

Comment: could you post an example of a link to an image?

Answer (score 1):

Try right click on the Image symbol on the page and check which location its referring to.
Most probably the image is under different folder structure and the application is referring to a different location.